# How do I use a TUDPSocket in Borland C++ Builder?

Tags: c++builder

Unfortunately I'm stuck with Borland C++ Builder and I need to recive UDP data. I have set up an TUDPSocket that can send data just fine, but I have no idea of how to get it to recive.

Does anyone have an example of that?

Do I need to set the LocalHost and LocalPort properties?

Can I use the OnRecive event?

The documentation I have found so far surfin the net is sparse and confusing... Oh, and I don't want to use Indy... The Indy components breaks everything on my machine. There is probably something wrong with the install but I don't have the time/mental strength to go and fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't C++ Builder share most of its libs with Delphi?  Maybe there is more documentation on the Delphi side of things that you can extrapolate from?

Worst case, can't you just use some other socket lib?

Comment: C++ builder: so much suck. Marking this as correct answer because I ended up using the ICS socket component instead.